# Is ‘despite that’ right?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

1. They can be instructed in swimming despite they are very young.
2. They can be instructed in swimming despite that they are very young.

Is sentence 1 or 2 right? Why?

Comment: From an ELU comment: [*For what it's worth, **despite that** can be used as a conjunction.*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/283939/explaining-despite-as-a-preposition#comment631715_283939) But for my money that usage (as reflected in your second example) is antiquated / archaic. Either "expand" the construction to *...despite **the fact that** they are very young*, or recast as *despite **being** very young*.

Comment: Usage differs here according to dialect, so it is difficult to give uncontroversial advice. The easiest solution is to use the conjunction `although` instead of the preposition `despite`: They can be instructed in swimming although they are very young.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Neither is correct. *Despite* is a preposition and should take either a noun or a gerund.

The usual expression using a noun is *despite the fact (that)*. The *that* is optional and makes the sentence sound slightly more formal.

> They can be instructed in swimming despite the fact (that) they are very young.

If you want to use a gerund, you should rewrite your sentence as follows:

> They can be instructed in swimming despite (them) being very young.
>
> They can be instructed in swimming despite (their) being very young.

*Their* and *them* are also optional in this case, since the subject of the gerund phrase is the same as that of the main clause. *Their* is more "proper" and formal.

---

As others have noted, *despite that* is still possible, but it's considered archaic or dialectal. The safest solution is either to use one of the two constructions I described above or rewrite that part using *although*:

> They can be instructed in swimming although they are very young.

Because *although* is a conjunction, it can be used with a clause.

Comment: Re the "gerund" versions (actually, I think ***them being*** is a straightforward "continuous [verb] participle* and only ***their being*** is a truly "noun-like" gerund), it might be worth noting that it's ***entirely optional*** whether to include *either* of the two possibilities ***them*** or ***their***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Just don't ask me whether ***being*** is a gerund or not *without* a preceding subject or possessive determiner! (I understand the difference if *either* of ***them / their*** is present, but I have absolutely no idea how to classify the syntax if *neither* are present! :)

Comment: ...belay that! In ***Being** young **is** not a disadvantage*, it's obvious that the first word must be a ***noun*** (because it's the *subject* of the verb ***to be***). The definition of a "gerund" is essentially *a verb form functioning as a noun*, and clearly that's how it's being used in my examples (but not in *this* actual sentence, obviously! :).

Comment: To me, "despite the fact they are[...]" sounds wrong to me, not informal.  Is that perhaps region dependent? (I'm Canadian)

Comment: @Spitemaster - Agreed, it sounds wrong to me too without "that." I probably wouldn't notice in fast speech though. (Midwest US)

Comment: *that they are young* can be the object required here. It sounds antiquated but not obsolete.

Comment: @Spitemaster *This is despite the fact they perform better in these subjects than their male counterparts. / We received a full refund, despite the fact we were due to fly that afternoon.* https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/despite (scroll down to the examples)

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that "that" can be used as a pronoun: "*They are very young. Despite that, they can be instructed in swimming.*" Here "that" is a pronoun referring to the concept "they are very young". -- The frequency of usage of "despite that" in this fashion is possibly part of the reason why Y. zeng is inclined to use "despite that" in their examples.

Comment: @athlonusm Be that as it may, I still think it sounds wrong.  Actually, thinking about it more, a phrase like *Despite that they are young, they can be instructed in swimming.* sounds better to me (if informal) than the sentence you provided, though I still agree that OP's sentence 2 is wrong.

Comment: I am a native speaker, and (2) is fine in my dialect.  I guess your dialect is different from mine.  Sentence (1) is certainly wrong.

Comment: @R.M. Yes, I did so.

Comment: I too think #2 is acceptable (if stilted).  It's not hard to picture say, [Maggie Smith](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Maggie_Smith) using that turn of phrase (perhaps change 'swimming' to 'spellcasting').  ;-)

Comment: @FumbleFingers For those nineteenth century linguists that believe in gerunds in English, a gerund is an *-ing* form of a verb that occurs in Subject, Object or Object of a preposition environments. That's as far as its nouniness goes (it occupies a position that we more freuently associate with nouns). Thus if there is a such a thing as a bona fide gerund in English, the *despite being very young* strings in the  OP's answer are definitely and indisputably gerunds. (But notice that's only if gerunds exist)

Comment: @Araucaria: [*It is said that **laughing** is infectious.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22laughing+is+infectious%22) I don't really care whether we call that highlighted noun usage a "gerund" or something else, but *syntactically,* ***laughing*** is equivalent to the more commonly used noun ***laughter*** there. And for some reason I'm not clear about, it doesn't seem natural to replace it with the infinitive in that *exact* context (***To laugh** is infectious* sounds a bit "off" to me). But I'm perfectly happy with both *Seeing is believing* and *To see is to believe*.